# Xcode,Swift M1macのデバックモードのみ、No such module 'module'というエラーが発生する。

Tags: swift

#### やりたいこととできないこと

現在、IntelMacで正常に動作しているswiftのプロジェクトをM1Macでも動作させようとしています。

M1macでもRereaseモードではビルドが通りますが、DebugモードだとFirebaseClasyliticsがimportできずNo such module 'FirebaseCrashlytics'というエラーが発生します。
FirebaseClashliticsを導入するにあたって、Fablicから移行したので公式の[この記事](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk#the_library_is_now_called_firebasecrashlytics)を参考にしました。

またimport FirebaseClashliticsをコメントアウトした状態で、再ビルドすると次は別ファイルのimport Alamofireの行でNo such module Alamofireとなりこのような感じでコメントアウトを続けていくと他のライブラリでもNo such module module名となることがわかりました。
予測変換でもimportの次はデフォルトで用意されているUIkitやFoundation以外は表示されていないこともわかりました。

#### 実施した手順とその結果

根本的な解決策は分からなかったので、下記のような対処をしました。

1. クリーンビルド
2. Xcode再起動
3. Mac再起動
4. DerivedDataの削除

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
   ```
5. キャッシュの削除

   ```
   $ rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
   $ rm -rf Pods
   $ pod install
   ```
6. podfile.lockの削除後にpod install
7. App.xcworkspaceを削除後、pod installで再度作り直し
8. [この記事](https://qiita.com/sensuikan1973/items/622349887c411d45242d)を参考にして

   ```
   pod deintegrate
   pod install
   ```
9. [この記事](https://qiita.com/nkekisasa222/items/716b2b525280ef602fb8)を参考にして
   Product/Scheme/ManageSchemes/を選択し、全ての項目のshowとsharedにチェックをつけてCloseをクリック。

このような一般的な対処法を一通り試してみましたが、No such module 'module'は消えませんでした。

#### 何を・どのように調べたのか

上記を解決するために、以下のキーワードで検索し上の８、９のような記事が出てきました。

・swift no such module

#### やりたくない対処法

業務で動いているソースでかつIntelmacとM1のリリースモードであれば正常に動作するので、既存コードの変更はできるだけしたくありません。

この問題を解決するにあたって何かアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いします。

**環境**

1. MacBook Air Mid2013 Intel,8GB
   Catalina
   Xcode12.4
2. MacBook Air (M1, 2020)M1,16GB
   BigSur
   Xcode12.5

### podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.21'
  pod 'DeployGateSDK'
  pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.2.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'SwiftFormat/CLI'
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64' if target.name.include?('Realm')
      end
    end
  end
  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Comment: エラーメッセージのごく一部だけを捉えて、ご自身の問題とは無関係の問題の対処方法を片っ端から試しているように見えます。エラーメッセージには他にどんな情報が含まれていますか? `m1 mac pod no such module`で検索してみましたか?

Comment: 検索していませんでした。アドバイスいただいたキーワードで検索してみたところ　https://qiita.com/Almond_0707/items/8453bc014e61b719c47c　この記事に辿り着き、ひとまずそれ通りにやると無事ビルドに成功しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 無事ビルドに成功したのであれば何よりです。ほとんど記事の再掲のような感じになるかもしれませんが、(引用元は明示した上で)ビルドに成功した対処方法を自己回答していただくと、他に同じことで苦しんでいる方々の役にたつかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事を参考にして、podfileの設定をシュミレータービルドの際にrealmだけでなく本体のプロジェクトごとarm64から除外する設定に変更すると動作しました。

[[XCode, M1] no such module in simulator](https://qiita.com/Almond_0707/items/8453bc014e61b719c47c)

また、こちらの記事も大変参考になりました。

[Xcode 12でシミュレータを対象にビルドできない場合やること](https://zenn.dev/yimajo/articles/7e275bc23999fe7d8b87)